# $_POST is null in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, null, codeigniter-3

when I'm login, the login controller will handle my login but Why my `$_post` in the controller is always false? (I know because is null but why is null?) and then is make me can't login to my home page. please, someone, help me

I have a controller like this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller  {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('M_login');
}

public function index() {
    //if user has log-in, redirect to somewhere
    if($this->session->userdata('loggedin')) {
        redirect('home');
    //else go to login form
    } else {
        if($_POST["username"]) {
            echo $this->M_login->ceklogin();
            redirect('login');
        } else {
            //if user input the wrong email/data
            $this->session->set_flashdata("msg_login", "Wrong credentials.");
            redirect('home/login');
        }
    }
}


}
```

This is my view

```
<?php
    $this->load->view('parts/header');
?>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">WoW Page</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login" method="POST">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('msg_login') != '') { ?>
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                                        <center><i class="fa fa-warning" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg_login'); ?></center>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" value="Login">
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is my model

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class M_login extends CI_Model {


        // cek login
        public function ceklogin() {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('admin', array(
                'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
                //password converted to md5
                'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password'))
            ));
            $user = $query->row();

            if(count($user) != 0) {
                //setting isi session
                $sesi = array(
                    'admin_id'=>$user->admin_id,
                    'username'=>$user->username,
                    'level'=>$user->level,
                    'loggedin'=>true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($sesi);
            } else {
                $data = array('loggedin'=>false);
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Thank You
Thank You
Thank You

Comment: Dont use `$_POST` - https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/input.html

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: can't you give me a source code will help me in this situation

Comment: Read the manual link I provided

Comment: I'am not understand it T.T

Comment: You use `$this->input->post('username')` in m_login so also use that instead of `$_POST["username"]`

Comment: I have to change to

if($this->input->post('username')) {
    echo $this->M_login->ceklogin();
    redirect('login');
   } else {
    //if user input the wrong email/data
    $this->session->set_flashdata("msg_login", "Wrong credentials.");
    redirect('login');
   }

but still null

Comment: Like this null too

if($_POST["username"]) {
    echo $this->M_login->ceklogin();
    redirect('login');
   } else {
    //if user input the wrong email/data
    $this->session->set_flashdata("msg_login", "Wrong credentials.");
    redirect('home/login');
   }

Comment: please note that your form is not pointing to any method on your Login controller. Form points to `index.php/login` which is the controller, but you should specify a method as well

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems. First one is that your model does not return anything that the controller can use. Here are my thoughts on how the model should be done.

```
public function ceklogin($user_name, $password)
{
    $user = $this->db
        ->select('admin_id, username, level')
        ->get_where('admin', array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>md5($password)))
        ->row_array();

    if( ! empty($user))
    {
        $user['loggedin'] = true;  //add 'loggedin' to $user array
        $this->session->set_userdata($user);
        return TRUE;
    }
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
    return FALSE;
}
```

Notice that there are two arguments to the function - `$user name` and `$password`. These need to be provided by the controller. Notice that `ceklogin()` returns TRUE or FALSE depending on if a row is found in the database.

I did not change the password hashing - *BUT YOU SHOULD*. Use the functions that @RiggsFolly told you about in the comments. You should also look into sanitizing and validating the inputs. **Never trust user input!**

Notice the database call returns a `row_array()` results. This will be the exact data structure you wanted for session data. That means you do not have to build an array for `set_userdata()` because the database made it for you.

Here is the revised `index()` function.

```
public function index()
{
    //if user has log-in, redirect to somewhere
    if($this->session->userdata('loggedin'))
    {
        redirect('home');
    }

    // get the inputs so they can be passed to the model
    $user_name = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    // if we have inputs, check for valid username & password 
    if($user_name && $password)
    {
        if($this->M_login->ceklogin($user_name, $password))
        {
            // model returned true
            redirect('home');  //if 'home' is where valid users go
        }
    }

    // If not all inputs (null/empty $_POST)
    // or the wrong inputs (ie. model returned false)
    $this->session->set_flashdata("msg_login", "Wrong credentials.");
    redirect('home/login');
}
```

I removed many (all) the `else` statements. They were not needed because all the `if` blocks end in a call to `redirect()` and that function calls `exit`; meaning that a call to `redirect()` never returns to where it was called from.

You should be using the CodeIgniter [Validation Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) instead of the crude construct

```
if($user_name && $password)
```

But that's better than nothing.